# SAPUI5 search field live search does not filter

Tags: list, search, live, sapui5

I am using search field in XML view.

```
<Page title="Title">
  <subHeader>
      <Toolbar>
        <SearchField
          liveChange="onSearch"
          width="100%" />
      </Toolbar>
    </subHeader>
  <content>
  <List id = "oProductList" items="{/formset}" select="whencliekedonlist" mode="SingleSelectMaster">
  <items>
  <StandardListItem title="{orderno}"
  description="{date}">



  </StandardListItem>
  </items>
  </List>
  </content>

  </Page>
```

On Init method of the view i am declaring the odata model

```
onInit: function() {
  //Declaring the model
  var oProductModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/SOL/TEST_SRV");
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oProductModel);
  debugger;
  },
```

I am listing the order no's in the screen split app master page.

now on livesearch i am calling this method which sets the filers

```
>   debugger;
>     // add filter for search
>     var aFilters = [];
>     var sQuery = oEvt.getSource().getValue();
>     if (sQuery && sQuery.length > 0) {
>       //here name is the field on which the filter has to be done.
>       var filter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("orderno", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery);
>       aFilters.push(filter);
>     }
>  
>  
>      
>     // update list binding
>   
>     var list = this.getView().byId("oProductList");
>     var binding = list.getBinding("items");
>     binding.filter(aFilters);
```

Issue: I am not getting the results filtered.Nothing happens when i filter.
 I am using odata model is it because of it?if so how to proceed can you point me to the code

Answer (score 0):

Execute the Odata request against your service with the $filter option applied. Most likely you will find that your service isn't filtering at all.

Filtering can be added by you via ABAP code or by configuring the UI2 Odata cache in Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following statement, exploiting the "search"-event, of the searchfield:

```
             <SearchField 
             search="handleSearch" 
             width="100%" > 
             </SearchField>
```

with handlesearch beeing my search handler
I've read somewhere that the liveChange event is set to false/inactive by default...i think there is a function with which you can check it...